# Prevent a div from Google being read and followed without JavaScript

Tags: seo, indexing, nofollow

I don't want some of divs on my page to be followed by Google because they contain duplicate content from other websites, is this possible that I prevent those `div`s to be 'no-followed'?

I have seen this: 
[Methods for preventing search engines from indexing irrelevant content on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973738/methods-for-preventing-search-engines-from-indexing-irrelevant-content-on-a-page)
but its suggesting JavaScript for this purpose and I can't use JS in my case, also that question is from 2009, I hope things are bit changed now?

Comment: There are countless search engines and no one can possibly speak for all. As you used the tag "google", does this mean you are only interested in Google? If not, you should add the relevant search engines to your question.

Comment: i am just interested in google :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want use javascript for this, **the only way I'm sure will stop Google for index some content of your page is using iframe + robots noindex/nofollow**.

1. Instead of use a div, create a normal iframe, in a way that it appears that is not a iframe.
2. To page that is target of iframe, add metatag robots `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">`

Keep in mind that it will probably be interpreted as if it were adversing, so there will be some penalty, but this penalty may be lower than copying significant amount of content.