# Prevent search engines from scanning preview of other pages

Tags: html, search, search-engine, google-search

I've got a website. After every article there is a big (7 sentences) preview for another article.

The problem is that google index this preview, and it makes my content duplicate.

How can I tell google not to read those previews?

Comment: +1 because I'm curious. However, in general, [you're not supposed to do things like this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355), and there's a chance it can cause Google to delist your website.

Comment: But those previews are random. They are not realy part of the page.

Comment: BTW, somone told me to use html5 tag aside, but I'm not sure if it works

Comment: Here's a thought: if the actual article shows up as the first result, is it actually a problem to have "duplicate" results? Perhaps the bigger issue is making sure the actual article shows up first.

Comment: Of course the first article shows up first, but when im searching in google for a sentence from the article,  it shows me results from random pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Methods for preventing search engines from indexing irrelevant content on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973738/methods-for-preventing-search-engines-from-indexing-irrelevant-content-on-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the preview section in a different span that would be hidden by Css properties and displayed using javascript at the time of page loading.Since the section is initially not displayed thus it would not be read by the search engine.

Dummy Html code

```
<span class="pgPreview">The preview for the next pages goes here </span>
```

Css code to hide it

```
.pgPreview {
display:none;
}
```

Javascript code to show it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $(".pgPreview").show();
  }
</script>
```

Assuming that you have the jquery  library included.

[Reference](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Comment: This prevents **the whole page** from being indexed, not a section of it.

Comment: Answer Updated as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

One effective though less-than-ideal solution could be to load the random article preview with Javascript. It's similar to how some blogs have a "click to load comments" button - they don't want their blog being associated in Google searches with everything their commenters say.

Since you're keeping the primary content of each page the same, I don't think this would be a [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355) issue, but no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

I know there used to be a system of labels such as:

```
<!-- googleon/googleoff: <index|anchor|link|all> -->
```

...but I do not know if that still works on these days...
also, I think it was only valid if you were using `google custom search`.
<sup>*(do not really know for sure)*</sup>

In any case, I can think in two ways to do what you need:

- A) Hide content in **iframes**
- B) Generate a **text-image** with that preview text

> ```
>   lolum dolimus
>   situs amen amdu etr   --> normal content
>   nulusan ar sindh ew
>  _____________________
> | lolum dolimus       |
> | situs amen amdu etr | --> iframe blocked with
> | nulusan ar sindh ew |     robots.txt file
>  ---------------------
>  _____________________
> | lolum dolimus       |     image with text
> | situs amen amdu etr | --> unreadable to
> | nulusan ar sindh ew |     search engines
>  ---------------------
> ```

Of course, both options are not completely infallible and depends solely on whether the search engine follow the directives in standardization and/or the ability to have OCR recognition.

Comment: Relevant: [Methods for preventing search engines from indexing irrelevant content on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973738/methods-for-preventing-search-engines-from-indexing-irrelevant-content-on-a-page)